# Compiling java down to native code

Tags: java, compilation, reverse-engineering

Is there any open-sourced compilers for Java that able to produce bytecode-less output? I'm selling a Java application and I it to stop people from reverse engineering my program and giving it away for free.

Comment: I would read [this article](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html) to get an idea of what's out there.

Comment: The risk of that is generally a lot less than you'd think (with the exception of some application areas). And is it not slightly ironic that you're looking for a free solution?

Comment: *"..stop people from reverse engineering my program.."*  If it's crap they won't bother.  If it is not crap, nothing will stop them (converting to native only makes it slightly harder).  Pursue this legally, not via programming.

Comment: did you see [the IKVM](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/java/#compiling-java-code-to-x86-code), RoboVM and [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to make java code hard to reverse engineer such as code obfuscators like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) but that won't stop someone from giving it away for free.

To stop people from giving it away you need to use some kind of serial key that is assigned to each customer.  At least that way if they give it away you know who did it.

Comment: *To stop people from giving it away you need to use some kind of serial key that is assigned to each customer.* Whoa? What stops them to rip-off code that checks serial key given they can read bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

If it runs on a computer, it can be reverse engineered. What you need is to use obfuscation. This way, your code will be harder to reproduce, because the logic in the obfuscated code is much more complex, than the code you originally wrote.

Comment: But reverse engineering assembler is a lot more complicated task than reversing java bytecode. And yes, there is also de-obfuscators.

Comment: Re obfuscators, you may wish to read my article _[Protect Your Java Code — Through Obfuscators And Beyond](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)_ (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of one of the tools mentioned in it.)